# Find the least number of moves required.

Tags: logic, contest-math, puzzle

> A move of a coin is defined as crossing any number of points in a straight line on the $4 \times 4$ grid (horizontally,vertically or diagonally). What is the lest number of moves in which a coin, starting from the indicated position, can cover all nine points within the marked square?

> [image]

I did it in $5$ moves. The way I did it is as follows $:$

[image]

Is it the optimal one or there are more efficient moves exist? Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT** $:$ **MY RE-ATTEMPT** $:$ [image]

Comment: @cosmo5 can you please check my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: But how to prove minimum number of moves required is exactly $4\ $? That only proves minimum number of moves required $\leq 4.$ Am I right @cosmo5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic puzzle. It can be done in 4 moves.
From your marked starting position: Down 2; diagonal up/right 3; left 3; diagonal down/right 2 (or 3)

Comment: I can't understand your notation. Can you please be more explicit? Thanks.

Comment: Star is at (2,1). (2,1) to (4,1) to (1,4) to (1,1) to (3,3).

Comment: If your marked points are coordinatized with $(0,0)$ being the lower left corner, $(3,0)$ lower right; $(0,3)$ upper left; $(3,3)$ upper right. Then $(0,2)\to (0,0)\to (3,3)\to (0,3)\to (2,1)$

Comment: @paw88789 can you please check my edit? Thanks.

Comment: @Phibetakappa Looks good.

Comment: But how to prove minimum number of moves required is exactly $4\ $? That only proves minimum number of moves required $\leq 4.$ Am I right?

Comment: I would try something along the lines of: Any given line covers at most $3$ points of interest. So you need at least $3$ lines. But the only way to cover in $3$ would be if all the lines were parallel.